# Toget specific value of user data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my application i have registration screen. It asks for username,email and password. I am pushing email and username to firebase realtime database. Suppose now the user log out from my application, uninstall the application and install it again and try to login . In login screen i am only asking for email and password, how can i retrieve the username of user. As user may uninstall the app after registration so Shared Prefrence won't work. I tried the following code but it does not give proper output.

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("userdetails");
 mMessagesDatabaseReference.child( auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("USERNAME")
```

My database looks like following

[image]

How to get username while logging as only email and password is asked while logging. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the user name, you need to attach a listener on that particular node. Please use the follwing code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("userdetails").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("USERNAME");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String USERNAME = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", USERNAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
pritish
```

Comment: I am getting error . java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: Is your `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` returning the correct user id?

Comment: I am getting auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() as dXV2xgnXxpNc50iZdnqYaQ30cNZ2 but in database it is completely different

Comment: I have one question, in your answer the second line should be rootRef.child("userdetails").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Oh, yes, i see. That's the problem. When you add data in the database, don't use the push() method, use `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`. And when you'll get, will work for sure.

Comment: Yes, should be `.child("userdetails")`. It's correct. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, because that id is not the user id, is an id that is generated by the push method. You need to remove that method and use `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` when adding data.

Comment: Your new records should look like this: `userdetails\dXV2xgnXxpNc50iZdnqYaQ30cNZ2` not as it is now.

Comment: I am using this to push data to database HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
                                    hashMap.put("USERNAME",name.getText().toString().trim());
                                    hashMap.put("EMAIL",inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                                    
                                    mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(hashMap);   What should i change , i am not getting you

Comment: You need to use this line of code: `mMessagesDatabaseReference.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(hashMap);`

Comment: Got it.. Thanks alot

Comment: I am getting null for dataSnapshot.child("USERNAME").getValue(String.class).   auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() i am getting  correct

Comment: Is `userdetails` a direct child of your Firebase root? Add a new screenshot of your Firebase database and the code to see where the problem is.

Comment: The screenshot is the same as above i mentioned in the question. Foll is my code mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("userdetails");
 mMessagesDatabaseReference.child( auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); Log.i("Saw", "onComplete: "+auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());mMessagesDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
Log.i("Pri", "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.child("USERNAME").getValue(String.class));

Comment: userdetails is a direct child of my Firebase root

Comment: It's correct. You need to use `mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("userdetails").child( auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());`

Comment: I got it. Please make the following change in your answer mMessagesDatabaseReference.child("USERNAME").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                            String USERNAME = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

Comment: Just added `.child("USERNAME")`. Cheers!